# XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My app, which works in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9cBy4RPx1HBTv6wmCcOb?p=info), does not work locally. It returns the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Amanuel/Coding/Angular.Js/page.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Why am I receiving this error?

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang= "en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Angular Js</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
    <script src = "https://rawgit.com/nirus/Angular-Route-Injector/master/dist/routeInjector.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app = "app">
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

page.html:

```html
Hello World
```

main.js:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])

app.config(function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'page.html'

  })

  .when('/helloUser', {
      template: "ds"

  })

  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  })

})
```

Here is a screenshot of the console:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular router implementation uses ajax for downloading template files. This doesnt work when we open the file directly. You need to start a server and open file from server for this to work.

You can use any server you like. Easiest that I do is install a http-server npm module and start server from the project directory like following.

If you already have node and npm installed. On command line do following.

```
npm install -g http-server
```

In project directory

```
http-server
```